Old TV sci fi series, portal to another world called Mongolia?
I want to find an old TV series i have watched when I was younger. It was about the son of this scientist that finds a portal to another world, I'm pretty sure it is named Mongolia. I remember it being like a desert, and the king that rules over it is very evil. The last episode had this boy and the daughter of the evil king electrocuting him, but before the king tell his daughter "Like father, like daughter."

How old is it? Was it in color? What language?

Could it have been "Mongo"?

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/FlashGordon2007

Yesss it was. Im soooo thankful. Its a very nostalgic memory for me

My immediate thought is a version of Flash Gordon.
The only version I am aware of with "portals" is the 2007 TV series.

The series was loosely based on the comic strip of the same name and incorporated elements from several previous adaptations, following the adventures of Steven "Flash" Gordon (Eric Johnson), a twenty-five-year-old who lives with his mother and whose scientist father was lost in a mysterious accident when Flash was 13 years old. Flash's ex-girlfriend, Dale Arden (Gina Holden), is a television news reporter and engaged to police detective Joe Wylee. They meet Professor Gordon's eccentric former assistant, Hans Zarkov (Jody Racicot), when rifts in space appear, allowing travel between Earth and the planet Mongo.





Yes its was that. Im very thankful to all of you

@Lisa Please demonstrate your gratitude bu clocking the checkmark at the upper left of this answer to show that you and the community accept it, and also perhaps give Paulie_D an up-vote?
